# rsession CPU usage when idle

Tags: macos, r, rstudio

I have recently noticed an issue with my R / RStudio installation.  When I have RStudio opened, the CPU usage in activity monitor shows the rsession and kernel_task processes hovering around 30% usage even when R is idle and not running anything.  I know this is a very vague description of the issue, I'm hoping someone here can give me pointers how to debug this issue or post more relevant information.

Thank you.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.2
```

Comment: Do you get the same issue when just R is opened?

Comment: @nograpes No - It seems like a RStudio specific problem.  If I close the current active project, the rsession CPU usage drops immediately and stays down even when I reopen it.

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar issue. When RStudio just start, the CPU usage is ~1%, but as soon I try to open a script the CPU usage start to increase, reaching ~80% and Rstudio doesn't respond. Any Idea how deal with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I had rsession running even when RStudio was not.  I found the process id of rsession, and killed it.  Then the computer fan stopped running overtime.  Not a chronic issue, tho

Answer (score 4):

If you are working in a specific Rstudio project, and this project has lots of files (hundreds or thousands) Rstudio may be trying to index the files -

I fixed this by:

1. From the Rstudio IDE while in a project,
2. Go to  `Tools` -> `Project Options`
3. Now click on code editing
4. deselect `Index R Source Files`
5. close everything and restart Rstudio

> Editing
>
> `Index R source files` — Determines whether R source files within the
>   project directory are indexed for code navigation (i.e. go to
>   file/function, go to function definition). Normally this should remain
>   enabled, however if you have a project directory with thousands of
>   files and are concerned about the overhead of monitoring and indexing
>   them you can disable indexing here.
>   `Insert spaces for tab` — Determine
>   whether the tab key inserts multiple spaces rather than a tab
>   character (soft tabs). Configure the number of spaces per soft-tab.
>   `Text encoding` — Specify the default text encoding for source files.
>   Note that source files which don't match the default encoding can
>   still be opened correctly using the `File : Reopen with Encoding` menu
>   command. [Source](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects)