# A Rstudio project causes the rsession memory to increase forever

Tags: r, memory, rstudio

Not sure it's a good place for this question. Maybe I should post in the RStudio list. So please tell me whether this question is not appropriate or close it and I will delete it.

On Windows 7, I've done a package which involves some C code (not Rcpp, only "standard" C code with SEXP and so on). The package works very well.

The problem is the following one. I've created a RStudio 1.1.442 project for this package. When I open this project, and *only* open this project (I even don't load the package), the memory consumed by the `rsession` increases forever, as I can see in the Memory Task Manager. So my only choice is to kill the `rsession`. This does not happen on Linux.

Any idea what causes this issue ? The issue occurs with R 3.4.4 and R 3.5.1. I have not tried another version of RStudio. When I open the folder in an editor like Atom, there's no problem.

Reproducible (?) steps:

- clone my package: [cxhull on Github](https://github.com/stla/cxhull);
- In Rstudio create a new project for this package, and build the package;
- Quit the project, and open it again;
- Open the Windows task manager, you will see that `rsession` consumes of lot of CPU and consumes some memory increasing forever.

I really don't understand because just opening a project doesn't load anything, AFAIK.

## EDIT

I've found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27911120/1100107). The reason is that there are two many functions in the package, and the file indexing is enabled. To disable it, you can do:

- Open the RStudio project file `xxx.Rproj` with a text editor
- Replace `EnableCodeIndexing: Yes` with `EnableCodeIndexing: No`.

I vote to close my own question. I prefer not to delete it, the information is useful.

Comment: Thanks; I think this is a well-posed question. It might not be the best avenue for Stack Overflow but you should consider posting this as a bug report at https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues.